# Error: ps command not found in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm getting an error while executing this bash script which prints 'hello' till a background process continues its execution.

```
ps command not found
```

I've done this couple of times before but not sure why I'm getting error this time.

```
./a.sh &
while ps -p $! > /dev/null; do
       echo hello
done
```

Comment: Did you mess with PATH? Do you still have /bin/ps?

Comment: I've verified this, PATH has this location to ps

Comment: what is the full output, does it run once and then stop? or does it immediately throw the command not found error?

Comment: It throws this error ./test.sh: line xx: ps: command not found and continues with execution of a.sh

Comment: "PATH has this location to ps" Well, clearly not. Either you've deleted ps, or messed up your PATH. `echo $PATH` and `ls /usr/bin/ps` will tell you which.

Comment: But I'm able to 'ps' from command line and it works fine..

Comment: In my machine, 'ps' is located in /bin rather than /usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't fix your apparent `PATH` problem, but there's a simpler approach to what you want to do than calling `ps` repeatedly.

```
# Start your script in the background, remembering its process ID
./a.sh & A_PID=$!

# Start another background job that echos hello (once per second, to
# avoid a flood of hellos). Remember its process ID as well
( while : ; do echo hello; sleep 1 done ) & LOOP_PID=$!

# Now wait for a.sh to finish...
wait $A_PID

# ... and kill the hello job
kill $LOOP_PID
```

Answer (score 0):

to debug this problem i suggest the following

```
 nohup ./a.sh &
 p1=$!

 while ps -p $p1 
 do
    echo hello
    sleep 1
 done
```